# Perform User Impersontaion from a Web Application

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm working a web application and I would like to allow administrators to perform user impersonation using a service account to authorize the calls to the APIs. I know how to do this for example on a python script using the .JSON file. But from a web aplication how do I handle the .JSON file, let's say the upload it to the Web application how do I perform user Impersonation from a web application using the JSON file or the information in it?

Comment: I know how to do it for example as documented at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests but how could I do it from a web application where there is no Json file on the direcotry of the application but instead is uploaded by the user of the app

Comment: Have you seen these threads? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47230956/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/60398882/  https://stackoverflow.com/q/28751995/