# Can't get analytics data to graphic I don't know what is problem

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

There is a problem, I can't pull the data and the chrt.js graph does not appear, what is the reason? I have this error on console but my id and API key is correct there is nothing wrong. Can someone help?

> Not a valid origin for the client: https://www.example.com has not been registered for client ID.
>
> There is a console error:
> Authentication failed idpiframe_initialization_failed

**Here is my code:**

````
function initGoogleAnalytics() {
    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': 'my_api_key',
        'clientId': 'my_client_id',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
        'discoveryDocs': ['https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4']
    }).then(function() {
        fetchAnalyticsData();
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('Authentication failed: ' + error.error);
    });
}

function fetchAnalyticsData() {
    gapi.client.analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet({
        'reportRequests': [{
            'viewId': 'my_view_id',
            'dateRanges': [{
                'startDate': '2023-01-01',
                'endDate': '2023-12-31'
            }],
            'metrics': [{
                'expression': 'ga:sessions'
            }]
        }]
    }).then(function(response) {
        var report = response.result.reports[0];
        var dataRows = report.data.rows;

        var labels = [];
        var sessionsData = [];

        dataRows.forEach(function(row) {
            labels.push(row.dimensions[0]);
            sessionsData.push(parseInt(row.metrics[0].values[0]));
        });

        var ctx = document.getElementById('CharTwo').getContext('2d');

        var CharTwo = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Number of Visitors',
                    data: sessionsData,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    tension: 0.1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        max: 1000
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('An error occurred while retrieving Google Analytics data: ' + error.result.error.message);
    });
}

function handleClientLoad() {
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initGoogleAnalytics);
}```
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068680/not-a-valid-origin-for-the-client-from-google-api-oauth