# adding authorized JavaScript origins to existing google api OAuth client ID credentials doesn't seem to have intended effect

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, oauth-2.0

My question is a follow up to an [answer to a related but different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42633937/3175120) https://stackoverflow.com/a/42633937/3175120.

I initially encountered the following error when i tried to set up an 'authorize/login' button on an html page.

> idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a valid origin for the
>   client: "MY DOMAIN" whitelist this origin for your project's client ID

I had no luck after going into my google API developer console to add the relevant domain under `Authorized JavaScript origins` to my existing credential.

After browsing around SO, I resorted to trying like the answer suggested to just create a new credential from scratch that includes the domains under authorized javascript origins **upon creation**. Doing so worked.

Now I don't understand why adding an authorized origin to an existing credential didn't work. Should it have worked? If not, I'd like to know why. But if I simply stumbled into buggy behavior, then perhaps validation here would be helpful so I could [report the bug](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to google's cloud platform.

Per the screenshots below: my "addHerokuAfter" credential did not work, but the "whitelistfrombeginning" credential did. They look identical though. The only difference is that with the "addHerokuAfter" credential, I added the authorized origin in after creating it.

Here is a list of my credentials:
[image: here is a list of my credentials]

This is what the non-working credential looks like.
[image]

This is what the working credential looks like.
[image]

Comment: did you resolve this in the end?

Comment: @byrnedo I do not believe my question got resolved in the end. I think I just worked around the problem, but never found the answer to my original question. But my memory is hazy because this was so long ago.