# Google API OAuth Client: Localhost never allowed for client ID

Tags: web, google-signin, google-identity

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid) guide, and re-visited the step multiple times, but cannot see what I am doing wrong here, if anything.

I have tried adding `http://localhost` and `http://localhost:80`, this is where my local server is running.

Whenever I attempt to prompt the user for sign-in, I am met with the error:

```
[GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.
```

I have tried to prompt using the `g_id_onload` `div` block which is described in the linked document, but I have also tried triggering the prompt via the JS API, same result. There are not many steps here, but am I missing something obvious? Does my consent screen need to be verified for some strange reason? I thought there was just a cap until it is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I have replicated the implementation below (using the same credentials as I was using before), and that seemed to work. But obviously no longer a supported method for implementing One Tap. I think this point to something being wrong on Google's end?

https://github.com/zapier/google-yolo-inline

UPDATE 2:
I have now attempted to deploy to a staging environment, adding the URL for that as an allowed origin. Same error in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue, my website instance had a referrer policy set to `no-referrer`. After setting it to `no-referrer-when-downgrade`, the One Tap prompt showed up as expected.

Comment: I just spent two weeks on this. You're a life saver! Thank you!

Comment: Hi @Flaying Plate
I don't understand what you mean exactly. Would you explain more about that?
Now I have a urgent problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform the local testing, did you use the URL http://localhost/path in your browser?

If you display One Tap in an iframe, the URL of that iframe should be something like http://localhost/path.

Did you request extra scopes in your OAuth client? if yes, it needs to be verified.

Comment: No additional scopes requested. 

As for local testing, I was just testing at the root of the website `http://localhost` when using the implementation provided in the Google guide.